# Correction of a streaming file without any containers

Tags: gstreamer

I have accidentally write a H264 data without any container using gstreamer by using following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.avi ! image/jpeg,width=672,height=378,framerate=15/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! filesink location=output.mkv
```

The correct pipeline should have been as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.avi ! image/jpeg,width=672,height=378,framerate=15/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! matroskamuxer ! filesink location=output.mkv
```

Now I have been trying to correct these streaming files, but I cannot find any appropriate solution yet.

Could you please give me suggestions on solution to this problem?

Regards.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no `matroskamuxer` element in gstreamer-1.0...it should be `matroskamux`. I do not understand your question...

Comment: Yes you are right it should be matroskamux, it was just a little typo. I have produced output.mkv files from input.avi files by using wrong pipeline in first line. Instead I should have used the second pipeline. Now mkv files cannot be neither played nor opened in any program. So I need to correct these files by using some appropriate way. Since  all mjpeg encoded files are deleted I need to correct x264 encoded files in some way.

Comment: ah, well, manually change their extensions to `.264` and try to read them into a gstreamer pipeline and push them to a .mkv container. Not sure on this though

Comment: I just tested that and it does not work. You may be out of luck as you may not be able to get any valid frames from the file. Only other thing is to manually read buffers of a known size from the file...but even then h264 does not encode whole frames each time and you would have to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by seeing if you can just extract the data and play it.  Then try and mux it.  Something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=output.mkv ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! ximagesink
```

You may have to tweak the caps, but then once you get it playing you can mux it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=output.mkv ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=good.mkv
```

Comment: This pipeline is not able to parse given file. Actually I need to add video width and height to caps because the original pipeline reported errors related to it. But as I've said even adding video width and height didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Are you on a Unix system?  Can you run h264_analyze and verify it actually got some h264 data to the files?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264bitstream/files/h264bitstream/0.1.9/

Comment: Yes I am on a Unix system. Here is the output of specified program:!! Did not find any NALs between offset 0 (0x0000), size 33554432 (0x2000000), discarding 
!! Did not find any NALs between offset 33554432 (0x2000000), size 67108864 (0x4000000), discarding 
!! Did not find any NALs between offset 67108864 (0x4000000), size 100663296 (0x6000000), discarding 
!! Did not find any NALs between offset 100663296 (0x6000000), size 134217728 (0x8000000), discarding 
!! Did not find any NALs between offset 134217728 (0x8000000), size 167772160 (0xA000000), discarding

Comment: If you're willing to post a link to one of the files I'll try and play it and build you a pipeline.

Comment: Hello, here you can find an example file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_lGAx2cxKbNSDhnNUplRmo5Sk0/view?usp=sharing Regards.

Comment: I'm not having any luck.  Could have sworn I'd done this in the past.  Maybe my other output had stream-format=byte-stream and alignment=nal.  Can't seem to get there from what you have.

I know it's a stretch but do you have any further logs from the original commands?  Maybe with full caps?